# Importing data from osm to postgis

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis

I have worked with osm2pgsql to import data from osm to postgis.
What other options do I have in order to do this?
I mean what other tools exist and which one is better?

And also I have problem in importing large amount of data to my database. Do I need extra big memoty capacity to do this? Like 64 GB RAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ogr2ogr with the [OSM](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_osm.html) driver. Apparently, you can even use [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for "other_tags". E.g.:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:dbname=osm" test.pbf \
    -lco COLUMN_TYPES=other_tags=hstore \
    --config OSM_MAX_TMPFILE_SIZE 1024
```

The configure option limits the internal processing in-memory SQLite DB size threshold to 10 GB (1024 MB), which you can adjust to any number of MB (default is 100 MB). Also, you will have five resulting layers—one for each geometry type. Give it a whirl.

Comment: for extra info :)     I have recently tried to import these data to postgre with 12 GB RAM and Windows server 2008 r2 64bit and in the middle of importing it give overflow error and stopped importing .

Comment: and how can I download ogr2ogr and OSM driver?

Comment: The two `-lco` are explained above. You can type it all on one line, I just use \ to split one command over several lines. I'm guessing the overflow error was with osm2pgsql. By far, the best way to install GDAL/OGR on Windows is http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ use "Advanced Install" and get at bare minimum "gdal", and use the Shell for all commands. The OSM driver is included with this build.

Comment: thanks a lot,  How many days it takes to import 22GB data?(Ram = 12GB)

Comment: it says two many features and ....  and says that you should use interleaver_reading=yes and when i use it, it not import completely

Comment: The OSM driver is new, If you think this is a bug you can submit a detailed report http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/